# How to properly initialize JUCE (NDK) in Xamarin application for Android

Tags: c#, android, c++, xamarin, juce

I develop Xamarin Application for Android, and I need initiliaze JUCE audio library in NDK (C++) context. I found, that JUCE has to be initialized by function:

```
static void initialiseJUCE (void* jniEnv, void* jContext);
```

I understand, that **jniENV** can be passed from C# code easily by:

```
[IntPtr] Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.Handle
```

to void* in C++

But I don't know how can I get **jContext**. Accordingly documentation, **jContext** is:

> @param jContext this is a jobject referring to your app/service/receiver/
> provider's Context. JUCE needs this for many of it's internal
> functions.

Honestly I'm not so familiar with Android development, so my question is maybe naive, and I don't see basic principles. Thanks.

Comment: I think you could create/use C# wrapper based on JUCE C++ library. An example like this [NowSound](https://github.com/RobJellinghaus/NowSound). And then use it for Xamarin

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly NowSound doesn't support Android (seems to). In config file I saw, that there is not define for OpenSLES support.

Problem is simply how get **jContext** (as IntPtr) in Xamarin for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point. From documentation for Java you mentioned looks like jContext is Application.Context (Android.Content.Context):

```
package com.rmsl.juce;
public class Java
{
    static { System.loadLibrary ("juce_jni"); }
    public native static void initialiseJUCE (Context context);
}
```

You can get it from your current activity,fragment or application.
So if you want to get pointer to your current Context try it for Xamarin.Android:

```
  //Context is a property of your Activity, Fragment or Application
  var currentContext = Context as global::Android.Runtime.IJavaObject;
  IntPtr pointer = currentContext.Handle;
```